# Performance Issue : Sql Views vs Linq For Decreasing Query Execution Time

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, linq, view

I am having a System Setup in ASP.NET Webforms and there is Acccounts Records Generation Form In Some Specific Situation I need to Fetch All Records that are near to 1 Million .

One solution could be to reduce number of records to fetch but when we need to fetch records for more than a year of 5 years that time records are half million, 1 million etc. How can I decrease its time?

What could be points that I can use to reduce its time? I can't show full query here, it's a big view that calls some other views in it

Does it take less time if I design it in as a Linq query? That's why I asked Linq vs Views

I have executed a "Select * from TableName" Query and its 40 mins and its still executing table is having 1,17,000 Records Can we decrease this timeline

Comment: you have a form that shows 1 million records!? You must have a really tiny scroll... Who needs 1 million records? Why not implement Paging and only show in groups of 25-50-100? Starting to think this is a UX question. Linq will be evaluated to sql. You should evaluate the query you wan't to run and the query linq is generating. You can focus on tuning your sql query. Can you supply execution plans?

Comment: Please provide your query and execution plan in `sqlplan` format

Comment: @mxix actually i am generating report with that query Not showing it anywhere on webform . Do you want me to share complete query with you

Comment: @Devart actually i am generating report with that query Not showing it anywhere on webform . Do you want me to share complete query with you

Comment: Your report must do some kind of aggregations... most of the times is best to ask sql-server to do it... instead of pulling all the data and run linq over it. If you want help. Yes you will need to supply as much information as you can about your query.

Comment: my single select * from table query is taking 45 mins to select data its having 1,17000 records is this speed ok and can we decrease this fetching time

Comment: that's very subjective, since you did not provide any information about your query.

Answer (score 0):

I started this as a comment but ran out of room.

Use the server to do as much filtering for you as possible and return as few rows as possible. Client side filtering is always going to be much slower than server side filtering. Eg, it does not have access to the indexes & optimisation techniques that exist on the server.

Linq uses "lazy evaluation" which means that it builds up a method for filtering but does not execute it until it is forced to. I've used it and was initially impressed with the speed ... until I started to access the data it returned. When you use the data you want from Linq, this will trigger the actual selection process, which you'll find is slow.

Use the server to return a series of small resultsets and then process those. If you need to join these resultsets on a key, save them into  dictionaries with that key so you can join them quickly.

Another approach is to look at Entity Framework to create a mirror of the server database structure along with indexes so that the subset of data you retrieve can be joined quickly.

Comment: Actually Getting that large number of rows is must thing . Like if we need records of 5 years . Actually i am not fetching complete set of data . I am only fetching Count() of records , Sum of Amount Paid , Sum of Other Expenses and these type of records . I am not printing all record of 5 years like employee details . I am only getting Sum of AMount paid and other type of aggregate function result and passing them on report